# Zabbix discovery item

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-api, zabbix-custom-reports

I migrated Zabbix to an another domain. I created all the items, Applications, Triggers and Discovery item as per the old Zabbix from a different domain. I have created 4 hosts and have created. all the items, Applications, Triggers and Discovery item as per the old Zabbix from a different domain. Out of the 4 hosts, 2 hosts that use zabbix agent is working. However, the other 2 hosts that use the discovery is not showing any latest data.

This is the discovery of one of the host
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Am quiet not sure if the zabbix conf file has to be updated. This the current zabbix conf file

```
# This is a configuration file for Zabbix Server process
# # To get more information about Zabbix,
# # visit http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_proxy

DBPassword=zabbix123
Hostname=zabbixproxy01
Server=zabbix20.company.com
DBUser=zabbix
JavaGateway=100.00.100.00
DBHost=localhost
DBName=zabbix
ProxyLocalBuffer=0
ProxyOfflineBuffer=24
StartJavaPollers=10
CacheSize=512M
HistoryCacheSize=64M
StartPollers=50
StartDBSyncers=4
StartTrappers=25
StartPollersUnreachable=80
ConfigFrequency=600
Timeout=30
LogFileSize=1
ExternalScripts=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.conf.d/externalscripts
PidFile=/var/run/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.pid
LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.log
LogSlowQueries=5000
StartDiscoverers=20
StartHTTPPollers=15
ListenIP=100.00.100.00
SourceIP=100.00.100.00
ProxyMode=0
ServerPort=10051
ListenPort=10051
SocketDir=/var/run/zabbix
DataSenderFrequency=30
```

Please let me know if there is any thing that am missing in the configuration.